# g++: error: .o: No such file or directory

Tags: qmake, qt5.5

I have written a simple pushbutton example code (Ubuntu 14.01) and it is giving me strange error after `make`.
Following is the `o/p` of `make`:

```
gcc -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o .o /
gcc: warning: /: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o PushButtonExample\ TEMPLATE\ =\ app main.o .o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
g++: error: .o: No such file or directory
make: *** [PushButtonExample TEMPLATE = app] Error 1
```

From above o/p, I am not really getting the meaning of `g++: error: .o: No such file or directory`, because it is not showing any file name. I searched for similar issue on Internet, but everywhere there is a file.o scenario.
Kindly help me through.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your .pro file as below:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = QtHelloWorld
QT += core gui
QT += widgets 
SOURCES += main.cpp 
SOURCES += mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
```

Comment: Why would this fix the problem? What was the issue?